# WCF - Threading at server to release to the client quicker

Tags: vb.net, wcf

When a function is call to the server, the file is uploaded and stored in a folder. Then the file must be processed which takes some time to do and would cause the client to timeout.

To work around this, I was thinking that by placing the processing of the file in a separate thread to allow the subroutine to return to the client once the file has been uploaded. And the processing of the file would continue in the background.

Unfortunately the thread is stopping the return. I don't understand what I'm having a problem with. I thought that by using the thread it would allow the subroutine to finish and return to the client.

```
Public Sub RestoreToOps(rFileInfo As RemoteFileInfo) Implements IRestore.RestoreToOps
    Dim oLogItem As New LogItem
    Dim sDestinationFolder As String = My.Settings.DestinationFolder
    Try
        Dim sFileDestination As String = Path.Combine(sDestinationFolder, rFileInfo.FileName)
        If File.Exists(sFileDestination) Then
            File.Delete(sFileDestination)
        End If
        Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(sFileDestination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)
            fs.Write(rFileInfo.FileBytes, 0, rFileInfo.FileBytes.Length)
        End Using
        ProcessFile(rFileInfo.FileName)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Error Handling
    End Try
End Sub

'*************************************************************************

Private Function ProcessFile(ByVal FileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim oThread As Thread = Nothing
    Dim oObject As Object = Nothing
    Dim oLogItem As New LogItem
    Dim sDBName As String = ""
    Dim bSuccess As Boolean = False
    Try
        If InStr(FileName, "Move.zip") > 0 Then
            sDBName = Replace(FileName, "Move.zip", "")
            oThread = New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf MakeRestoreFromObject))
            oThread.IsBackground = True
            oThread.Start(sDBName)
            oThread.Join()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Error Handling
    End Try
    Return bSuccess
End Function
```

The function "MakeRestoreFromObject" takes a considerable amount of time and when using the coding above the subroutine waits for the function to finish before returning.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oThread.Join()` is causing your main thread to block until `oThread` completes. Just remove that line of code.